# PulseAudio Preferences (paprefs) without a desktop GUI

Tags: raspberry-pi, headless, pulseaudio

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi with a docker mopidy service ([wernight/mopidy](https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/mopidy)).

To follow this step:

```
Launch paprefs 
(PulseAudio Preferences) > "Network Server" tab > Check "Enable network access to local sound devices" (you may check "Don't require authentication" to avoid mounting cookie file described below).
```

I need a desktop GUI. I do not have one. How can I set this via the command line?

Comment: After so many years of this question, I am still stuck facing the same issue. You have any idea on how to do that?